# Uploading a Picture (with Title) to Facebook Page through App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

So I wanted to do the following: a php script should upload a picture with a title to a facebook page.

I then googled around a bit and found this: [Simple example to post to a Facebook fan page via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php)

Everything works fine, but sadly the result is not what I wanted. Instead of a "full" image, I only get a cripple: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHhIb.jpg

Can you help me out? The script will need offline access and I've already an app. I will only need it to upload pictures along with a title, nothing more.
Before this I was uploading pictures through the Email provided by Facebook for mobile users, but that's not satisfying anymore. I mean, it can't be that hard. But if I don't figure this out, I will rent a virtual windows server and run a script that loggs into Facebook and posts the image.

Comment: You need to upload the picture to a page or post on the page? Title says: upload, and the screenshot indicates that you are trying to post on page.

Comment: @Sahil Post on the page, sorry. I am the owner of the page so I want to upload a new picture for all fans to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload a picture to your page using-

```
$image['file'] = PATH_TO_PICTURE;
$args = array( 'access_token' => PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, 'message' => '','no_story' => 0);
$args['image'] = '@' . $image['file'];
$target_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$target_url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

**PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN**

1. Get the list of pages/apps-

   ```
   $facebook->api("/USER_ID/accounts");
   ```
2. Get the pages' access token-

   ```
   $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
   ```

Comment: How can I set the album to the "default / system album" of the page? I am talking about the "album" where pictures get uploaded by default (when not selecting any album at all).

Comment: Figured out the solution by myself. Simply enter the page id as album id. Thanks, I got it working using your help!

Comment: I have one more question. The app now throws the "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time" error. How can I get a permanent access token?

Comment: Check this out for the user's extended token: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13809431/facebook-acces-token-expires-after-3-4-refreshes/13972025#13972025

Comment: Use THIS extended token and then repeat the process mention above for the PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN, this will give you the page_access_token that is immortal until and unless the secret key of the app is refreshed :)

Answer (score 1):

This will load up a picture to a specific gallery:

```
$newphotodata = array(
'access_token' => $fanPageAccessToken,
'message' => $message,
'no_story' => 1,
'aid' => $albumId,
'image' => '@' . $picturePath);
$uploadedphoto = $facebook->api('/' . $albumId . '/photos/', 'post', $newphotodata);
```

You need the following permissions too though:

```
read_stream, manage_pages, publish_stream, photo_upload, user_photos, user_photo_video_tags
```

I'm not sure whether the user_photos and user_photo_video_tags are actually needed, so try without if you get it working with.

Also, you need the following line before you make the call:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
```

You basically need to do two things first though.

First you need to query the API to get an access token for whatever page you want to post to.

You do this by the following api call:

```
$fanpages = $facebook->api('me/accounts?access_token='.$accessToken);
```

You then loop through $fanpages['data'], to find the page you want:

```
$fanPageAccessToken = $fanPage['access_token']
```

You then make the call given above, using the appropriate album id.

Now, if you don't know what album id you require, take a look at the following:

```
$fan_albums = $facebook->api($fanPageId.'/albums/');
```

This will show all the albums. The key fields at the moment will be ['id'] and ['name'].

Once you have made the post, there will be no evidence of it. So what you should then do is post a link to the photo on the links feed. If you need help with that then ask and I will provide the info.

Alternatively, check out these two articles I wrote a while ago, which cover the same thing.

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=262

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=322

Comment: Hi, I think I can ask you too: how can I create a permanent session token?

Comment: Check this out from the fb docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/