# Posting to a facebook page wall as a user not the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the facebook php sdk to try and post to a facebook fan page from my page tab application.

I can get the code to work if it posts as the page by requesting the "manage_pages" permission like this post:

[Simple example to post to a Facebook fan page via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php)

However I want to post as the user who accessed my page tab application and not the page itself. If I remove the "manage_pages" permission I get the following error:

"(#200) The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories"

This is some of my code:

```
$fbPermissions = 'publish_actions,publish_stream';

    //Call Facebook API
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $appId,
      'secret' => $appSecret
    ));

    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

    //Post variables we received from user
    $userPageId     = "999792964025950"; 
    $userMessage    = $_POST["reason"];

    if(strlen($userMessage)<1) 
    {
        //message is empty
        $userMessage = 'No message was entered!';
    }

    //HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/feed with the publish_stream
    $post_url = '/'.$userPageId.'/feed';

         //posts message on page statues 
    $msg_body = array(
       'message' => $userMessage,
    );
        $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
```

I really can't work out why this is and what is going on. I've tried setting the access token but to no avail.

Comment: Well, have you asked th user for one of the permissions that allow posting on his behalf during login?

Comment: I believe so, I asked for: "publish_actions" & "publish_stream" permissions. As far as I know these are all that's needed. Should I be asking for anything else?

Comment: I just asked because I don’t see you doing that in your code.

Comment: Yeah I didn't include the login & auth code:

$fbPermissions = 'publish_actions,publish_stream';

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$redirecturl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));

can you see any issues with this?