# Facebook / JavaScript API: Post big picture with external link?

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

Using Facebook Graph API I can post a link with a picture to `/feed`, but I already learned that if I want a **big** picture I should post to `/photos`:

```
var postParams =
  {'url': 'http://example.com/mypic.jpg',
   'link': 'http://example.com/mysite.html'};
FB.api('/ID/photos', 'post', postParams, function(respPost) {...});
```

ID could even be a group Id (I tried). However, the 'link' doesn't work. Clicking on the published picture simply takes me to see it in a bigger mode.

How can I post a **big** picture that links to an **external** site?
I did see posts like this...

*Note: there is a related older stackoverflow post that refers to using php and does not seem to help here:* [Posting a link via the Facebook graph API with a large picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173609/posting-a-link-via-the-facebook-graph-api-with-a-large-picture)

Comment: You can not post a link _and_ a photo, you need to chose either one.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will display your post with a small or big picture automatically depending on what its algorithms feel is best for your content. You cannot manually request how your story will be displayed on timeline/newsfeed beyond providing the message / images you wish to share via Open Graph tags.