# Renew or create permanent Facebook access token to post app page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After following the steps of the answer marked correct on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php), I was able to post to my Facebook page via my app, the problem is the access token expires after 2 hours, I have gone through so many articles and found a lot of different ways but can't get them to work, I want to be running this script every our with cron jobs so i post different articles to my page, is there no way of getting a permanent access token?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

Create a long lived access token using a facebook application.
Currently the long-lived user access_token will be valid for 60 days while the short-lived user access_tokens are currently valid from 1 to 2 hours.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/

You can create your own application and create a user accesstoken from it by logging in through it.