# Generating long-lived facebook access_token for political ads library

Tags: python, facebook, curl, facebook-ads-api

I currently generate an access token in pretty much the same steps as @skylarcheung outline's  [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Ad-Library-API-Script-Repository/issues/3#issuecomment-638988172) however I'd like to try to do this programatically instead of manually every 60 days. With access to the app id and secret, what call would I need to make to get the token, and then extend it?

Currently trying the following to get the token:
`response = requests.get(f"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials")`

but the returned app_token does not work when I try to pull political ads data or try to extend it:
`second_response = requests.get(f"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={app_token}")`
(The request to extend follows the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544444/facebook-long-lived-access-token))

The error I get is:

```
{'error': {'message': 'Application does not have permission for this action', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 10, 'error_subcode': 2332004, 'is_transient': False, 'error_user_title': 'App role required', 'error_user_msg': 'You need to be assigned a role by the app owner to continue. Learn more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles', 'fbtrace_id': '*******'}}
```

(I am ID-verified to pull ads from the political ad library per [the reqs](https://www.facebook.com/ads/library) and when I manually generate the token and extend it I am able to pull ads without issue)

Comment: please read [mcve] and adjust your question above accordingly. Good luck.

Comment: You need a user access token for these requests, but what you created is an app access token. (And no, you can not create user access tokens programmatically.)