# Facebook App to Post HTTP GET to Timeline

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, get

A lot of the documentation online is pre open graph, and I find the Facebook developers documentation quite confusing (I'm a novice developer). Can someone please tell me, at a high level, how or where I might find out how to go about creating an app in Facebook where I can post to my business' page timeline through a single encoded HTTP GET (or similar) request.

I understand I might have to make a simple FB app and authorize it to talk with a separate web app. But I'm just looking at pointers at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it isn't quite correct that you can only find pre-open graph things on Facebook. Anyhow, to post, you need an access token. 
What you seek to do is update your fan page via app, if I get it correctly. 
That isn't done with just one url: you need to call at least two:
1) one call is to authorize the app and get an access token
2) the second call is to get your accounts (fan pages) with ids and access tokens
3) the third call is to update your fan page via app.
The url to post via app would be `https://graph.facebook.com/$your_id/feed` with the following parameters: access_token, message (the message you want to post, not required), link (if any. Not required.), image (not required), description (not required), caption (not required), etc. You need at least a message or a link for the post. If you use php the easiest is a curl POST call. I've found something for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php), by the way

Comment: OK great.. it's that simple:) That's what I was hoping. Yes I meant 3rd party tutorials and questions on here were out dated. Everything on FB was more around actual app development. Whereas I just want to post to FB via HTTP. Tell me, will the access token be specific to my business FB page? I'm assuming I won't need to click and the curl POST will be sufficient to post to the page.

Comment: And I assume the first two calls are only done once yes?

Comment: you need page tokens and page ids to post on pages. And yes you can do it with curl without clicking. Store access tokens and ids, and you just make one call

Comment: I just wanted to come back to say I have it working already! Thanks for the pointers and link to the other question. You saved me a lot of running around:) Now to make my Web app:)

Comment: Do you know if there is a limit to posts? Because after about 30 successful test posts with my web app it simply stopped working.

Comment: Hmmm I got another token and it worked. Is there a time limit? How can I overcome this? I can't authorise every couple of hours.