# Posting to Page Via Facebook API - Mentioning (linking) friends and Pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-opengraph

I'm using the facebook open graph api to post to a facebook fan page. More info on the method can be found in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833145/1901781).

When one manually posts on facebook they can use @ to link a particular person e.g. `@Michael Jackson`. This auto populates a link to that persons page and shows up on their timeline. The @ itself dissapears once the post has been made, leaving only the hyperlinked text i.e. `Michael Jackson`.

Programatically compiling a post via the api, including the @, results in the text being posted in plain text. i.e. `@Michael Jackson` shows as `@Michael Jackson`.

How can I escape, or otherwise parse the anchor through the api so that Facebook recognises it as a link to another user/page?

Edit: I found [this reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/) which describes these links as Actions, specifically in this case a 'Mentioning friends' action. It goes on to explain the syntax of `@[USERID]` or `@[USERNAME]` which is promising. But if I compile this encoded it posts the plain encoded text e.g. `%40%5BUSERID%5D`, when left un-encoded the post fails.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that starting your message with a mention tag (i.e. @[12345678:User Name] ) throws a CurlException error.

To fix this I changed:

```
    'message' => '@[1234567890:User Name]';
```

To

```
    'message' => ' @[1234567890:User Name]';
```

Simply adding a space before the mention seems to fix that problem.