# How to post image/content to facebook page from website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post a message/image on facebook created page.I have created the functionality in my website admin section to upload image,add contents but need to know how can i post directly from website to my facebook page .

I have created a website in php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to post pictures and status in FB using PHP. See the below link..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php

Comment: I have not used any facebook sdk in php.can you provide any example or code how to share images/content.

Comment: You can find the codes here. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: and also this will help u. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/