# how to post on facebook using php?

Tags: php, facebook

I already searched many times in google to find out how to post on facebook using php code, of course I found many results but unfortunately I don't which one is right , I tested all of them , please some one help me out how to do this, my php version as a below:

```
`Apache Web Server Version 2.2.8
PHP Script Language Version 5.2.6
MySQL Database Version 5.0.51b
phpMyAdmin Database Manager Version 2.10.3`
```

I need your help guys.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: hhhh I know , but give tutorial or something, let me ask one question I wanna post on fb via localhost Can I ?

Comment: yes. but try to use some virtual hosts for for url issues.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by virtual hosts , I think you mean the convans url and secret convans url am I right ?

Comment: i mean to say something like `www.example.dev` instead of `localhost/project`

Comment: Try this step by step instruction. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php

Comment: thanks gusy , please have a look the above image this is right or not ? your comment