# Social network auto posting from PHP applications

Tags: php, facebook, api, class, social-networking

[image]

I have PHP websites with admin panels where i add news or products. For example as you can understand from the image, i add news with header,date,photos and content. If i click any of those radio buttons, news will be posted to any social network.  I had tried facebook Graph API's and worked good some but not totally as i wanted becasue had problems with tokens valid days. Anybody has any idea which and how i can use library or API?

Comment: Would be easier to help if you share your code.

Comment: Codes are not important i think in this topic. I am looking for any idea how to share news or products at same time when i add from admin panels of my websites.

Comment: Here is the way of PHP+cURL with Facebook GraphAPI to post to facebook which i used. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818667/simple-example-to-post-to-a-facebook-fan-page-via-php

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension